# Does spark supports the below cascaded query?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have one requirement to run some queries against some tables in the postgresql database to populate a dataframe. Tables are as following.

table 1 has the below data.

```
QueryID, WhereClauseID, Enabled
1        1              true
2        2              true
3        3              true
...
```

table 2 has the below data.

```
WhereClauseID, WhereClauseString
1              a>b
2              a>c
3              a>b && a<c
...
```

table 3 has the below data.

```
a,   b,  c,  value
30,  20, 30, 100
20,  10, 40, 200
...
```

I want to query in the following way. For table 1, I want to pick up the rows when Enabled is true. Based on the WhereClauseID in each row, I want to pick up the rows in table 2. Based on the WhereClause condition picked up from table 2, I want to run the query using Where Clause to query table 3 to get the Value. Finally, I want to get all records in table 3 meeting the WhereClauses enabled in table 1.

I know I can go through table 1 row by row, and use the parameterized string to build sql query to query table 3. But I think the efficiency is very low to query row by row, especially if table 1 is big. Are there some better way to organize the query to improve the efficiency? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it important that the WhereClauseString is dynamic? I mean, does it have to be a table, or could they be somewhat hard coded? If you share your usecase it'll be much easier to help you out with this!

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the dynamic WhereClauseString is the key in my use case. Let me mention more about my use case. So based on the user's input, another microservice needs to write the dynamic WhereClauseString into table 2 in PostgreSQL DB. The spark job is referring to this table to query other tables. The key point is that different sql query statement is needed for different row based on the WhereClauseString.  So I thought to ask Spark job to go through table 1 row by row to build the SQL statement. The problem of this solution is that we need query the database once for each SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you usecase, but for pyspark databases, you'd might be able to solve it using the [`.when`](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/) statement in pyspark.

Here is a suggestion.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

tbl1 = spark.table("table1")
tbl3 = spark.table("table3")

tbl3 = (
    tbl3
    .withColumn("WhereClauseID", 
        ## You can do some fancy parsing of your tbl2 
        ## here if you want this to be evaluated programatically from your table2.
        (
        F.when( F.col("a") > F.col("b"), 1)
        .when( F.col("a") > F.col("b"), 2)
        .otherwise(-1)
        )
    )
)
tbl1_with_tbl_3 = tbl1.join(tbl3, "WhereClauseID", "left")
```

Comment: Thanks! So it is to read all tables from PostgreSQL DB back to Spark job at first. right? The three tables may be big. However, we are only interested in the final query results. Do you think it is a better way to implement some view and/or stored procedure to implement such logic in PostgreSQL DB? Then, the spark job just need query once to get the final results.

Comment: Ah. Then this would be a PostgreSQL question, and not spark I think :)

Comment: Yeah, this logic can be implemented in either Spark or PostgreSQL DB. Just do not know what is the best practice. For PostgreSQL DB, I am also interested in knowing if there are some advanced feature to support such dynamic whereclause scenario.